# Добавить название купона в заказах Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в список заказов в админке добавить показ названия купона?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в functions.php активной темы

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woo_customer_order_coupon_column_for_orders' );
function woo_customer_order_coupon_column_for_orders( $columns ) {

    $columns['order_coupons'] = __('Coupons', 'woocommerce');

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'woo_display_customer_order_coupon_in_column_for_orders' );
function woo_display_customer_order_coupon_in_column_for_orders( $column ) {
    global $the_order, $post;
    if( $column  == 'order_coupons' ) {
        if( $coupons = $the_order->get_coupon_codes() ) {
            echo implode(', ', $coupons) . ' ('.count($coupons).')';
        } else {
            echo '<small><em>'. __('No coupons') . '</em></small>';
        }
    }
}
```